# Como obter cada item de um XML?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml

Em minha aplicação em Node.js, tenho essa resposta em `XML`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<checkout>
    <code>meucode</code>
    <date>minhadate</date>
</checkout>
```

Que está nessa variável:

```
var response;
```

Como posso pegar os dados que estão em `<code></code>` e em `<date></date>` no Node.js?

Answer (score 3):

A maneira mais simples, ao meu ver, seria usar uma biblioteca para fazer o *parse* do XML para um objeto JavaScript/JSON.

Poderia usar o [`fast-xml-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-xml-parser) no Node.JS:

- Instalaçao

```
npm install fast-xml-parser
```

- Uso

```
const parser = require('fast-xml-parser');

const jsonObj = parser.parse(response); // "response" é a sua variável
```

Exemplo usando uma CDN:

```js
const xmlData =
  '<bookstore><book>' +
  '<title>Everyday Italian</title>' +
  '<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>' +
  '<year>2005</year>' +
  '</book></bookstore>';
  
const jsonObj = parser.parse(xmlData);

console.log('XML em JSON:', jsonObj);

// Acessando as propriedades deste objeto:
console.log('"title" do xmlData: ', jsonObj.bookstore.book.title);

// simulando seu código
const response =
  '<checkout>' +
  '<code>meucode</code>' +
  '<date>minhadate</date>' +
  '</checkout>';

const responseObj = parser.parse(response);

console.log('dados do "response":', responseObj);
console.log('"code" do responseObj:', responseObj.checkout.code);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fast-xml-parser/3.18.0/parser.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Obrigado deu certo.